# Offset value in Image data matrix and its effect on integer value

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix

Currently I am trying to understand the OpenCV's face detection API `DetectionBasedTracker`. Inside the code, I found the definition

```
#define CALC_SUM_(p0, p1, p2, p3, offset) \
    ((p0)[offset] - (p1)[offset] - (p2)[offset] + (p3)[offset])
```

I can't figure out the followings

(1)p0, p1, p2, p3 are integer values. What is the return value of `(p0)[offset]` and what does it do?

(2)Actually offset is the number of integers in one row of image matrix. Say if image matrix is 480 x 640. There are 640 integer values in one row of image data. Say for the second row, offset = 640. It is calculated as `offset = pt.y * ((int)image.step/sizeof(int)) + pt.x`; By changing the `offset value`, how `(p0)[offset]`has effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `p0` is *not* an integer, but rather a one-dimensional array.

If that is correct, the macro would be calculating the "sum" of the `offset`th items in arrays `p0`, `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`, except that it's a strange sum because of all those `-` signs.

**Edited: having now looked at the code in question**

I find the code hard to follow, but let's try anyway:

My conclusion is that `p0[offset]` is a pointer to a pixel in an image (an integer value).  That pixel is one corner of a rectangle in the image. `p1[offset]`, `p2[offset]`, and `p3[offset]` are pointers to the pixels at the other corners of the same rectangle.

In more detail...

`CALC_SUM_` is called by `CALC_SUM` which is called in a lot of places, such as in `HaarEvaluator::Feature :: calc`.

In that `calc` function, `CALC_SUM` is called with `p[0]` as an argument.  `p` is defined in `struct Feature` as `const int* p[RECT_NUM][4]`, so `p[0]` is an array of four pointers to `int`s.

What might these four `int`s be?  Well, they are undefined immediately after the `Feature` constructor is called, since the pointers are set to be NULL.

But assuming `HaarEvaluator::Feature :: updatePtrs` has been called at some point, the pointers are updated by the `CV_TILTED_PTRS` or `CV_SUM_PTRS` macros.

Both of those macros take a pointer to a *matrix* of values, which I assume is a matrix of pixels in an image (given the task at hand, which is finding a feature in an image).  That pointer is called `titled` or `sum`.  Let's work with `sum`.  The four pointers in `p[0]` are set by `CV_SUM_PTRS` to point to four corners of a rectangle within `sum`.

When the `calc` function is called, the four pointers (`p[0]` contains the four pointers to corners `p[0][0]`-`p[0][3]`) are passed in along with an offset.  This offset is effectively added to each of the four pointers, using array notation, which shifts the rectangle around the image.

The actual sum looks like it could be doing the fast computation described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features#Fast_computation_of_Haar-like_features).

Comment: Looking in `cascadedetect.hpp`, it looks very much like `p0` is a _pointer_ to an integer.  See the line `const int* p[RECT_NUM][4];` in `struct Feature`.  What is your basis for thinking it is an integer?

Comment: Yes you are right. I use LBPEvaluator at Line number 190. Actually p is const int* p[16]; inside Feature structure. Each p[i] is pointer to integer. But pointing only to one integer. So what does (p0)[offset]do? Because it is pointing to only one integer.

Comment: I have edited my answer to try and address your second question.  Where you have a pointer `x`, `x[offset]` adds `offset` to the pointer (not to the value pointed to, but to the pointer itself).

Comment: ...and having added `offset` to the pointer, it is dereferenced so that you get the value of integer at that location.

Comment: Yes p0 is pointing to array of integers. I found at #define CV_SUM_PTRS( p0, p1, p2, p3, sum, rect, step ) (line37, cascadedetect.hpp)